# Return a string value based on XPATH condition

Tags: xpath

If I have the below XML, how to specify a xpath to return a string based on a condition. For example here `if //b[@id=23] then "Profit" else "Loss"`

```
<a>
  <b id="23"/>
  <c></c>
  <d></d>
  <e>
    <f id="23">
       <i>123</i>
       <j>234</j>
    <f>
    <f id="24">
       <i>345</i>
       <j>456</j>
    <f>
    <f id="25">
       <i>678</i>
       <j>567</j>
    <f>
  </e>
</a>
```

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a pure XPath 1.0 one-liner expression. :)

Comment: Also added extensive explanation and the obvious XPath 2.0 solution.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**I. XPath 2.0 solution** (recommended if you have access to an XPath 2.0 engine)

```
   (: XPath 2.0 has if ... then ... else ... :) 

   if(//b[@id=23]) 
     then 'Profit' 
     else 'Loss'
```

**II. XPath 1.0 solution**:

Use:

```
concat(substring('Profit', 1 div boolean(//b[@id=23])),
       substring('Loss', 1 div not(//b[@id=23]))
      )
```

**Verification using XSLT 1.0**:

This transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:value-of select=
   "concat(substring('Profit', 1 div boolean(//b[@id=23])),
           substring('Loss', 1 div not(//b[@id=23]))
          )"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document** (corrected to make it well-formed):

```
<a>
    <b id="23"/>
    <c></c>
    <d></d>
    <e>
        <f id="23">
            <i>123</i>
            <j>234</j>
        </f>
        <f id="24">
            <i>345</i>
            <j>456</j>
        </f>
        <f id="25">
            <i>678</i>
            <j>567</j>
        </f>
    </e>
</a>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
Profit
```

**When we replace in the XML document**:

```
<b id="23"/>
```

**with**:

```
<b id="24"/>
```

**again the correct result is produced**:

```
Loss
```

**Explanation**:

We use the fact that:

```
substring($someString, $N)
```

is the empty string for all `$N > string-length($someString)`.

Also, **the number `Infinity` is the only number greater than the string-length of any string**.

Finally:

`number(true())` is `1` by definition,

`number(false())` is `0` by definition.

Therefore:

`1 div $someCondition`

is `1` exactly when the `$someCondition` is `true()`

and is `Infinity` exactly when `$someCondition` is `false()`

**Thus it follows from this that if we want to produce `$stringX` when `$Cond` is `true()` and to produce `$stringY` when `$Cond` is `false()`, one way to express this is by**:

```
concat(substring($stringX, 1 div $cond),
       substring($stringY, 1 div not($cond)),
      )
```

**In the above expression exactly one of the two arguments of the `concat()` function is non-empty**.

Comment: +1 Dimitre you always provide outstanding explanations, especially to questions involving XPath. I speak from experience :)

Comment: I'm using a variant of the XPath 1.0 solution and it is working great. Many thanks.

concat(substring($stringX, 1 div $cond),
       substring($stringY, 1 div $otherCond)),
      )

Comment: @DanLugg that's a nice thing to say Dan. Just speaking as a bystander. Keep it up :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't; you'd have to use XQuery for this. see e.g. [XQuery Conditional Expressions](http://www.w3schools.com/xquery/xquery_syntax.asp)

Or, if the resulting string is only used within Java, you can just process the value returned by XPath within your Java code:

```
XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xpath = factory.newXPath();
XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//b[@id=23]");
boolean result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.BOOLEAN);

if (result) return "Profit";
else return "Loss";
```

Comment: I am using JAXP for xml processing. How to use this xquery in this?

Comment: If you're using JAXP, then why not just test for the retrieved string value on the Java side?

Comment: My issue is based on the node attribute value I have to decide on the result string. When I tried to retrieve the string nothing comes in as this node just has one attribute <b id=23/>. If I give the conditon like //b[@id=23] it is returning a boolen value.

Comment: Can't you check if that boolean value is true, and return the appropriate string based on that? e.g.

   if (node_has_attribute) return "Profit" else return "Loss";

Comment: yes I checked and the value returned is true, but I don't know how to return "profit" for true. Any sample code would really help me.

Comment: see added example code -- it really is just what I said before; just take the boolean value from evaluating the XPath expression, and test it with a Java 'if' and return / assign the proper string there.