# Conditional xpath with Java

Tags: java, xml, xpath

I have a sample xml file which looks like the one below:

```
<Root>
    <SubOne>
       <book author="george" />
       <indiv name="abc" />
       <indiv name="khh" />
       <indiv name="ioo" />
    </SubOne>
    <SubTwo>
       <indiv book author="hamle" />
       <indiv name="kok"/>
       <indiv name="ppp" />
    </SubTow>

</Root>
```

Is there a way in XPATH to check , if author="george" select /Root/SubOne/indiv/@name , or if the author="hamle", select /Root/SubTwo/indiv/@name.
Any help is appreciated

Comment: Look at this question [Return a string value based on XPATH condition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7045151/return-a-string-value-based-on-xpath-condition)

Comment: @codewagge, i saw the post . Want i would like to have is ,implementing the condition in a java program.

Comment: You might get more help if you include that info in the question.

Comment: Java isn't my area, hopefully the new tag and title will catch the eye of someone who does Java.

Comment: It is much better to google a how-to than to ask for a specific piece of code on SO. People will help you find solutions but they won't provide coding service.

Comment: @parameswar: Refer to my **[answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11233547/500725)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I noticed that your `XML` is not valid.

Assume that your XML is as follows.

### XML:

```
<Root>
    <SubOne>
        <book author="george"/>
        <indiv name="abc"/>
        <indiv name="khh"/>
        <indiv name="ioo"/>
    </SubOne>
    <SubTwo>
        <book author="hamle"/>
        <indiv name="kok"/>
        <indiv name="ppp"/>
    </SubTwo>
</Root>
```

### XPATH:

For `@author='george'`, use this XPATH:

```
//*[book[@author='george']]/indiv
```

For `@author='hamle'`, use this XPATH:

```
//*[book[@author='hamle']]/indiv
```

For both XPATH, to print the name use `@name`

### JAVA:

Using Java, you need to implement this way for both xpath's

For `@author='george'`,

```
String xpath = "//*[book[@author='george']]/indiv";
NodeList nl = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate(xpath, xml, XPathConstants.NODESET);
for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
    System.out.println(nodes.item(i).getAttributes().getNamedItem("name").getNodeValue()); 
}
```

For `@author='hamle'`,

```
String xpath = "//*[book[@author='hamle']]/indiv";
NodeList nl = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate(xpath, xml, XPathConstants.NODESET);
for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
    System.out.println(nodes.item(i).getAttributes().getNamedItem("name").getNodeValue()); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have a typo in node /Root/SubTwo/indiv.
This should work (I haven't check)

```
/Root/SubOne/book[@author='george']/following-sibling::1/@name | /Root/SubTwo/book[@author='hamle']/following-sibling::1/@name
```

It uses union so thats not exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Let me know if you check this. In addition to emulate true 'if' clause you can consume only first attribute in the result.

Comment: @victor, actualy i am trying to implement this in java .

Comment: i tried it, it is  throwing an error, " Attribute name "book" associated with an element type "indiv" must be followed by the ' = ' character."

Comment: Fix the typo first: '<indiv book author="hamle" />' It has incorrect XML syntax.

Comment: I have fixed the typo. How do i implement this in java ?