# Xpath: Simple condition Check and assign value in Xpath Expression

Tags: xml, xpath, xml-parsing

I need do a check condition and  if the condition not satisfies need to hard code the value. Below is my xml.

I need to check the condition like inside subroot- if ItemType=Table1 and ItemCondition=Chair1 then i have to give a hard coded value 'Proceed'( this hard coded value i will map to target side)

```
   <Root>
      <SubRoot>
          <ItemType>Table1</ItemType>
          <ItemCondition>Chair1</ItemCondition>
          <ItemValue>
              .......
           </ItemValue>
      </SubRoot>
      <SubRoot>
          <ItemType>Table2</ItemType>
           <ItemCondition>chair2</ItemCondition>
           <ItemValue>
               .......
           </ItemValue>
       </SubRoot>
   </Root>
```

I have tried like this but not seems to be working

```
      /Root/SubRoot[ItemType='Table1' and ItemCondition='Chair1']='Proceed'
```

Could you please anyone help on this. Thanks in advance.

Edited:

```
 if (SubRoot[ItemType ='Table1'  and ItemCondition ='Chair1']) then 'Proceed' else 'Decline'
```

Comment: @derp: Thank you. if the condition fails i have to send a hard coded value 'proceed'( i'm checking the 2 attribute value ItemType and Item Condition). I'm using a tool build on top of JAVA. Xpath version could be a latest one. i have proceeded with if else condition as well ( Edited in question) but no hope.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you didn't specify whether you were transforming a document entirely or not, I'm going to answer with the assumption that you are working on XML elements individually in your code somewhere.

There is a trick that I use often for "if" conditions in XPath:

```
substring(<default_text>, 1 div <condition>)
```

What that does is basically give you the `<default_text>` if the right side ends up as `1 div <non-zero value>`. So in your case, maybe you can do:

```
substring("Proceed", 1 div boolean(//Root/SubRoot[ItemType="Table1" and ItemCondition="Chair1"]))
```

That should give you "Proceed" for only elements that match those conditions you specified.

However, I noticed in your edit that you also want an "else" value. Once you understand the method I just showed you, then you can do some clever concat work to give you exactly what you want:

```
concat(
    substring("Proceed", 1 div boolean(//Root/SubRoot[ItemType="Table1" and ItemCondition="Chair1"])),
    substring("Decline", 1 div not(//Root/SubRoot[ItemType="Table1" and ItemCondition="Chair1"]))
)
```

So if the element meets those conditions, you should basically get `concat("Proceed", "")` which results in "Proceed", and `concat("", "Decline")` which results in "Decline" for an element that does not meet those conditions.

Comment: Thank you for your support. I tried to implement first logic to test. But it is throwing error like `Arithmetic operator is not defined for arguments of types (xs:integer, xs:boolean)`. Could you please help on this. Thanks in advance

Comment: What language/library/etc are you using to implement XPath?

Comment: i'm using Mule ESB , where i have datamapper to load source and target. source side we can also have a option of using xpath ( there where i'm trying ). version 3.5.1

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with Mule ESB. But I can assure you that it's valid XPath 1.0 syntax. I tested it with lxml.

Ha, I also just found an SO answer where someone does the exact same thing in XPath: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7048664/639806. Maybe boolean() is conflicting with some internal Mule function? Do you pass the whole XPath as a string?

Comment: Thanks in Tons and Tons. It helps me to resolve the solution. Yes, it a valid condition check.

Answer (score 0):

XPath is used for selecting Nodes or NodeSets. I think you should check XQuery and generate new XML file.

It will be like

```
   for $x in /Root/SubRoot
   return   if ($x/ItemType='Table1' and $x/ItemCondition='Chair1')
   then <SubRoot>'Proceed'</SubRoot>
   else $x
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. Then this will not be possible in xpath!. Because i have a limitation , can able to use only xpath