# How to get XPath to return a placeholder default value when no match is found?

Tags: xml, xpath, xpath-2.0

A subset of my XML data looks like this.

```
<results>
  <result>
    <finishedSqFt>2608</finishedSqFt>
    <bedrooms>3</bedrooms>
    <totalRooms>9</totalRooms>
    <lastSoldDate>05/25/2001</lastSoldDate>
  </result>
</results>
```

My goal is to use a single Xpath expression to extract an array of the string-values of the following elements:

```
[ finishedSqFt, bedrooms, bathrooms, lastSoldDate, ]
```

*Notice the* `bathrooms` *variable is not included in my data.*

The Xpath expression I am using is as follows:

```
(//results/result/finishedSqFt)[1] | (//results/result/bedrooms)[1] |
(//results/result/bathrooms)[1] | (//results/result/lastSoldDate)[1]
```

The result I get is:

```
[ 2608, 3, "05/25/2001", ]
```

The result I want is:

```
[ 2608, 3, "default", "05/25/2001", ]
```

How do I accomplish this? How do I insert a default value when the xPath does not return a match?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Mowzer, Simply put, an XPath expression doesn't always need to only refer to nodes.

Comment: Also added a pure XPath 1.0 solution, in case you cannot use XPath 2.0. See the updated answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Use this XPath 2.0 expression**:

```
'[',
 string-join((/*/*/finishedSqFt/string(), 
              /*/*/bedrooms/string(), 
              (/*/*/bathrooms/string(), 'default')[1], 
              /*/*/lastSoldDate/string()), ', '),
 ']'
```

---

**XSLT 2.0 - based verification**

This transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:sequence select=
    "'[',
     string-join((/*/*/finishedSqFt/string(), 
                  /*/*/bedrooms/string(), 
                  (/*/*/bathrooms/string(), 'default')[1], 
                  /*/*/lastSoldDate/string()), ', '),
     ']'
    "/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<results>
  <result>
    <finishedSqFt>2608</finishedSqFt>
    <bedrooms>3</bedrooms>
    <totalRooms>9</totalRooms>
    <lastSoldDate>05/25/2001</lastSoldDate>
  </result>
</results>
```

**evaluates the above XPath expression and outputs the result of this evaluation -- the wanted, correct result**:

```
[ 2608, 3, default, 05/25/2001 ]
```

---

**II. XPath 1.0 solution**

```
concat('[ ',
        string(/*/*/finishedSqFt), ', ',
        string(/*/*/bedrooms), ', ',
        substring(string(/*/*/bathrooms), 1 div boolean(string(/*/*/bathrooms)) ),
        substring('default', 1 div not(string(/*/*/bathrooms)) ),    
        ', ',
        string(/*/*/lastSoldDate), 
        ' ]'
        )
```

**XSLT 1.0 - based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:value-of select=
    "concat('[ ',
            string(/*/*/finishedSqFt), ', ',
            string(/*/*/bedrooms), ', ',
            substring(string(/*/*/bathrooms), 1 div boolean(string(/*/*/bathrooms)) ),
            substring('default', 1 div not(string(/*/*/bathrooms)) ),    
            ', ',
            string(/*/*/lastSoldDate), 
            ' ]'
            )
    "/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the sameprovided XML document, the same correct result is produced**:

```
[ 2608, 3, default, 05/25/2001 ]
```

For explanation of the XPath 1.0 solution see **[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7048664/36305)**